# Outlook 2003 suddenly crashing and when booted, view has changed. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook

XPPor SP3.

I recently added Lookout http://www.vinodlive.com/2008/01/23/lookout-microsoft-outlook-search-tool-still-works/ and it is great.

However, since I did this, Outlook has started crashing randomly, and when I reboot it, the view has changed so that the reading pane is no longer on the right side where I want it.

Can this be fixed?

EDIT: It only seems to crash when I change the reading pane. When I leave it the way it re-sets to, the program does not crash. I miss the way I had it - much more useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Outlook in safe mode. There is a command line option to do that. In this case it should  disable add-ons.

Comment: How does this help me?